# Are "wrapper" and "shim" synonymous?

Tags: abstraction, terminology

Are the words "wrapper" and "shim" more or less synonymous, or is there a distinction, perhaps connotative?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A shim is typically something written specifically to maintain backwards compatibility. For example, if you have two versions of an API, version 1 and version 2, then rather than maintaining version 1 independently of version 2, you might write a *shim* that intercepts calls to version 1 of the API, translates the parameters to what version 2 requires, and then returns the results.

Typically, a shim is written by the provider of the API, rather than consumer.

A wrapper is written by the *consumer* of an API and is typically written so that you can switch the underlying API without the rest of your code having to know. For example, you might write a database wrapper so that you can talk to MS SQL Server, or Oracle, just by switching wrappers.

Of course, as with any terminology, there are gray areas, but I think the above covers the main differences.